# Immutable js object typescript interface

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

I have a JS object with deeply nested values:

```
let IObj = {
    a: {
        b: string
    };
    d: string;
};

let obj: IObj  = {
  a: {
    b: 'c'
  },
  d: 'e'
}
```

I want to make it immutable:

```
let immutableObj = Immutable.fromJS(obj);
```

Which interface is implemented by immutableObj?

Comment: You may also check out https://github.com/engineforce/ImmutableAssign, which is a lightweight immutable helper that supports TypeScript type checking, and allows you to continue working with POJO (Plain Old JavaScript Object).

Answer (score 1):

> Which interface is implemented by immutableObj?

Sadly it returns an `any`. So it is completely unchecked.

## Source

https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/68d1b90b3343da918badb70bfd998724d2a6be99/dist/immutable.d.ts#L86-L89